# Why the image is not appearing to the left of text

Tags: html, css

If I comment out the img tag the text appears as it should.  How do I get the text to appear to the right of the img tag?

```css
div,p{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0"  />
<p> Some text</p>
</div><br>
<div >
<ul>
  <li>This photo is amazing</li>
  <li>Great view!</li>
  <li>But why are the bullet points in the photo??</li>
  <li>Good question, indeed!</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The title and the question do not match. In the title you ask why the image is not left of the text, but in the body you ask how to get the text to the left of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `float: left;` to align image in left and made ul to display inline, please check example below:

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}

ul{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.clear {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0" />
  <p> Some text</p>

  <ul class="clear">
    <li>This photo is amazing</li>
    <li>Great view!</li>
    <li>But why are the bullet points in the photo??</li>
    <li>Good question, indeed!</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Going to explain your answer, or do you plan on treating it like a game of spot-the-difference and expect us to figure it out?

Comment: What was the purpose of applying a clear to the `ul` element?

Comment: The solution was self explanatory since I used only float to align image. Though I have added the same context.